# React-big-calendar - sort(set order) allDay events

Tags: react-big-calendar

React big calendar receives an array with objects:

```
allDay: true
end: Sat Jan 13 2018 03:03:00 GMT+0200 (EET) {}
eventType: "video"
start: Sat Jan 13 2018 03:03:00 GMT+0200 (EET) {}
title: "0"
```

There can be 3 types of EventType - video, duration and audio,
but they are displaying completely in random order.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKRtb.png)

Need an advice how to set an order?